# Can I deploy backed up outbound change set after sandbox refresh?

Tags: change-set, sandbox-refresh

I want to get my outbound change set back in my sandbox after it is refreshed. Till now, I can backup my outbound change sets with *sfdx force:source:retrieve* command. But I can not deploy these again to my sandbox after it is refreshed.
How can I do that, can anyone help me out there?